# How can I open vscode:// links in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need to open (Linux) a link of type vscode://some-extension?token=xyz, but it doesn't work, vscode never opens.

[image]

My code.desktop is:

```
cat ~/.local/share/applications/vsc.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Visual Studio Code
Icon=code
Exec="/opt/apps/vsc/bin/code" %f
Comment=VSC
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
Path=
StartupNotify=false
Keywords=vscode;
```